# Bounding a solution for an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given
$$\dot{x}=t\cdot \sin^2(xt), \quad x(0)=0 \quad t\in[0,1]$$
I need to bound the solution to that ODE.

I know that $\lvert \dot{x} \rvert = \lvert f(x,y) \rvert \le 1$, but how can I continue from here and bound $x$ itself? I don't know how to approach that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation tells you that $\dot{x}(t)\geq 0$ for all $t$, so let's forget about the absolute value. Moreover, since $\sin^2\leq 1$, we have
$$\dot{x}(t)\leq t$$ for all $t$, and integrating we have
$$\int_0^s\dot{x}(t)dt\leq \int_0^stdt \Rightarrow x(s)\leq {1\over 2}s^2,$$ so $1/2$ is a bound, since you are saying $s\in [0,1]$.

Anyway, notice that this procedure can be iterated: since $\sin \theta<\theta$ for positive $\theta$, you can conclude that $\dot{x}(t)\leq {1\over 2}t$, which now gives $1/4$ as a bound. Continuing like that, you have what @juliàn was saying: $0$ is actually the only solution.

Comment: Thanks. I can't detect the use of the IV though. Why is it needed?

Comment: You need it to say that $\int_0^s\dot{x}(t)dt=[x(s)-x(0)]=x(s)$

Comment: Oh, of course..

Answer (score 5):

Well, the unique solution is $x(t)=0$ for all $t$.